# Unable to download my CSV file on Safari using PHP

Tags: php, csv, safari

I am facing with strange problem while exporting my csv file on safari it is just displaying on browser instead of downloading .While same code is working with Firefox and Crome.I have searched but nothing is working for me. Please help. Here is my code-

```
<?php
ob_clean();
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');    
header('Expires: 0');

function exportData() {

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, array('Market ID', 'Market Name', 'Suburb', 'State', 'Start Time', 'End Time', 'Status',"~"));
include "database.php";


$dbquery = @$_POST['query'];
$queryAllUser = $dbquery;       


$resultAllUser = mysql_query($queryAllUser);
$countAllUser = mysql_num_rows($resultAllUser);


if($countAllUser > 0)
{
while($rowMarketId= mysql_fetch_assoc($resultAllUser))
{  

   $marketId =     $rowMarketId['mrkt_id'];
   $isCancel =     $rowMarketId['is_cancel'];
   $openning_tim = $rowMarketId['openning_time'];
   $closing_tim =  $rowMarketId['closing_time'];
   $suburb =  $rowMarketId['suburb']; 
   $name =  $rowMarketId['name'];
   $state =  $rowMarketId['state'];       
   if($isCancel == 0)
   {
            $status_type = "Open";
   }
    else
    {
            $status_type = "Close";
    }

      $val = array();
      $val[] = $marketId;
      $val[] = $name;
      $val[] = $suburb;
      $val[] = $state;
      $val[] = $openning_tim;
      $val[] = $closing_tim;
      $val[] = $status_type;
      $val[] = "~";

     fputcsv($fp, $val);

  }


  }


  }

   exportData();

  ?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it depends on the CSV reader you have installed on your browsers. Same applies with PDFs

Comment: @JulienLachal - thanks for response but I have tested it with more than three systems having different version of safari but still same problem.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm telling you, maybe Safari isn't able to read CSV as Firefox and Chrome do. How does it read them, do you have a special plugin for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .urlencode(basename($filename)));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
```

Try With this Headers........ This should Work..

Comment: Prashant - thanks for comment but it is not working.

Comment: www.123contactform.com/docs/i-cannot-download-csv-file-on-safari-what-to-do/.......... Check Out this link

Comment: Thanks  for response @Prashat , I have already followed that site . But my client wants automatic download of CSV file.